# How to discard trailing "/" per -> //localhost:8080/mysite/

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I'm using sing spring 3.2.2. How can I discard the trailing "/" in my index.jsp page?

When I type in my url as

```
//localhost:8080/mysite
```

it ads the trailing /

**Currently appends trailing "/":**

```
//localhost:8080/mysite/
```

**I want it to show up as:**

```
//localhost:8080/mysite
```

Comment: Is this an issue of the URL not showing up in the browser the wayyou want it to?  What happens when you try navigating to `//localhost:8080/mysite`?  Does the browser append the extra `/`?

Comment: @willOEM: nav to //.../mysite appends the extra /

Comment: @willOEM: yes, you are totally correct...adds the trailing /.  is this something that i can modify with mapping or default welcome config?  thx!

Comment: This is probably an issue that needs to be solved through web server configuration rather than Spring configuration.  Your application's root address is `/`, so this will be the default URL, but `localhost:8080/mysite` is synonymous with `localhost:8080/mysite/`.